# PDF.js showing blank page in ios

Tags: javascript, ios, pdf, browser, pdf.js

I'm using [PDF.js](http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/) to show pdf on my website. It works fine most of the time but in iOS devices, it shows an empty page and doesn't show any error in the console. I've tested in Chrome, Firefox, and Safari browsers, all show the same blank page.

How can I solve this problem? Thanks in advance!

[image]